# nodemon does not recharge with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

I'm trying to mount an api to a js node with docker, all works fine but unfortunately when I make a change to a file, docker does not update files and nodemon doesn't update server, which forces me to always restart the `docker-compose up --build` command.

My tree :

```
|- api
  |- src
    |- app.js
    |- index.js
    |- routes.js
  |- .dockerignore
  |- .editorconfig
  |- .env.example
  |- .package.json
|- app
|- docker-compose.yml
```

my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "NODE_ENV=development"
  # front:
  #   build: ./front
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./front:/usr/src/app
  #   ports:
  #     - 3000:3000
```

My dockerfile in /api :

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "exampleApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "an example app",
  "author": "Jean Bon <jeanbon@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "lint": "esw -w src test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "babel",
    "boilerplate",
    "scaffold",
    "es6",
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "jest",
    "eslint"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.3.2",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.3",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "transform-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
      "import",
      "jest"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2017,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "jest/no-focused-tests": 2,
      "jest/no-identical-title": 2
    }
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

in my terminal, nodemon works but when I make a modification nothing moves :

[docker-compose log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U01mu.png)

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Which files are you changing and how are you changing them?

Comment: I just changed the string in the json (file : routes.js) to see after on postman if the answer changed.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try running nodemon using `-L` flag: `nodemon -L app.js`

From [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add --watch on your script. Try this:

> nodemon --watch src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register\""

See more on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), take a look on the **Monitoring multiple directories** part.